# c# - WAV file trimming and adding silence

Tags: c#, audio, ffmpeg, wav, naudio

I have two recordings of same event, different lengths, started at different times. I want to synchronize them, time offset is known. I want to achieve the following:

1. Align second one in time by the time offset.
2. Trim second one to match the length of the first one
3. When there is nothing to trim, add silence to match the length of the first one. 
   I found the way to trim the audio, but I couldn't find solution for adding silence. Is there any way to do this with NAudio, ffmpeg or Aurio?

Comment: This can be done with ffmpeg. Provide details on the durations and what offset/trim/silence is needed and I'll write up a command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way to write silence by millisecond using NAudio:

```
public static void WriteSilence(WaveFormat waveFormat, 
   int silenceMilliSecondLength, WaveFileWriter waveFileWriter)
{
    int bytesPerMillisecond = waveFormat.AverageBytesPerSecond / 1000;
    //an new all zero byte array will play silence
    var silentBytes = new byte[silenceMilliSecondLength * bytesPerMillisecond];
    waveFileWriter.Write(silentBytes, 0, silentBytes.Length);
    waveFileWriter.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: I went back to my project and tested your solution. And it works! Can't believe how easy it was. I'm marking your answer as a solution, since it's much easier and clear to understand

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for not responding, but I solved my problem with use of ffmpeg. Here's how I've done it:
`ffmpeg -f lavfi -i aevalsrc=0:d=8.375 -i inputfile.wav -filter_complex "[0:0] [1:0] concat=n=2:v=0:a=1" -ss 0 -to 63.787 outputfile.wav` 
 `-i aevalsrc=0:d=8.375` generates silence for duration (`d`) of 8.375 seconds.  
`-filter_complex "[0:0] [1:0] concat=n=2:v=0:a=1` merges silence and input file.  - [Concatenation](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate)
`-ss 0 -to 63.787` trims the output (from a start to the length of first file, that is 63.787, if input is shorter than that, output file has input file duration) - [Seeking](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Seeking)
If offset value is negative, then it's:
`ffmpeg -i inputfile.wav -ss 22.316 -t 54.213 outputfile.wav`
So the output file is the input file starting from 22.316 seconds for the duration of 54.213
I used NReco.VideoConverter as a ffmpeg wrapper.